# Fill data when open "Post on wall" dialog

Tags: android, facebook, post

In my application user can share information with different apps using:

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Link from my APP");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://aaa.com/");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share via:"));
```

It works fine./gmail,sms,google+..../
The only problematic app is Facebook. It starts dialog, but there is no info in fields.
Tried different TAGs, bout nothing :(
The only result is: If I put URL as EXTRA_TEXT - it not shown as text, but Facebook dialog read tags from URL and place them on dialog frame.

Any ideas to fill data in dialog.
Already have code to share wia sdk with or without dialog but this is not good for some reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problems disappear after putting correct Android Key Hash.
Now share works correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate facebook sdk

Go through the following link it shows how to integrate facebook sdk

[http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/][1]

and u need to put some code in your java file as follows

```
try {
            String response = facebook.request("me");
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", " your link");
            parameters.putString("description", "");
            response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                    "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
               Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
            }
     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: I already have this code working. Problem is: I want to give user chance to select application from list "Intent.createChooser"....I dont know selected application so I have to put data in Intent and provide proper tags.